# WCF returns different parts of IPv6 Address

Tags: wcf, ipv6

I'm using the code below to get the IP address for the client in my WCF

```
  OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
  MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
  RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty =
            messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]
            as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
  return endpointProperty.Address;
```

If I run a `ipconfig` on my client, I get:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3864:610a:3dc:5acd%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.249
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.250
```

My problem is that, on some calls, I receive from my code `fe80::3864:610a`, and so other calls I get `fe80::3864:610a:3dc:`

Is this a correct behavior? Can, or should, I filter this?

Comment: The code you use works fine for me.  Just before the return, I added **Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Client Address == {0}", endpointProperty.Address));**  Perhaps the issue is in what you do with the IPAddress after it is returned.